# In which maven repo can I find Eclipse RCP 3.6 Jars?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp

We have an Eclipse RCP application based on Eclipse 3.6. Recently our builds have started to fail (local repository of CI agent was probably deleted for some reason), as certain Eclipse dependencies cannot be found in the maven repository.

I can't seem to find them anywhere on the web. Can anyone point me to a maven repository where these artifacts can be found?

Here's an extract from our pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.commands</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.I20100512-1500</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.v20100505</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These artifacts can be found in Maven central.  Our Nexus repository is showing them in a search, but the version number for `org.eclipse.core.commands` just `3.6.0`.  In both cases, they have a different group ID.

Try this ([look here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.core%7Corg.eclipse.core.commands%7C3.6.0%7Cjar)):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.commands</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and this ([look here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.core%7Corg.eclipse.core.runtime%7C3.6.0.v20100505%7Cjar)):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.0.v20100505</version>
</dependency>
```

Sometimes these things just get moved around in Maven Central....and then your Nexus rebuild indices and poof - they're gone.